# run r.stats as a quiet module in GRASS-Python script

Tags: python, grass-gis

Has anyone else used r.stats as a quiet module in a GRASS-python script?

As part of my program I'm using:

```
grass.run_command("r.stats", flags='l', input=<file>, output=<*.csv file>, fs=',')
```

I'm using the 'l' flag here to print out category labels.  If I change the flags to 'lq' r.stats does not produce the specified *.csv file.  If I use the flags as '-q', r.stats runs as a quiet module, but it only creates a *.csv file with one row that describes the category values.  For my output, I need both category values and their respective labels.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to set the `-q` flag in a GRASS-Python script inside a `grass.run_command()` is `quiet = True`. In the example given in the question (for grass64), that would be:

```
grass.run_command("r.stats", flags='l', input=<file>, output=<*.csv file>, fs=',', quiet = True)
```

Read also the GRASS-Wiki page [GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library) for examples.

Comment: Despite the original question being "old", it is still a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out a solution.  Probably will only work for GRASS-PYTHON codes.

In the environmental variables portion of my script I added:

```
os.environ['GRASS_VERBOSE']='0' #runs modules silently
```